# C# Facebook SDK Get Image Picture Unknown facebook response

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using C# Facebook SDK https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-csharp-sdk downloaded from **Nuget** in my MVC application to get public Albums from page.

All requests work fine except one, when I'm trying to get album cover.

```
var PictureUrl = "1713516952246958/picture";
var PictureResult = FB.Get(PictureUrl);
```

It throws an exception **"Unknown facebook response."**

Same request works here

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=1713516952246958%2Fpicture&version=v2.7

Any ideas what should be a problem?

Answer (score 5):

I had exactly the same problem and it was driving me nuts.

Eventually I thought to check the documentation:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture/

Basically it says:
`By default this edge will return a 302 redirect to the picture image. To get access to the data about the picture, please include **redirect=false** in your query.`

So the "unknown facebook response" error you were getting was because instead of valid JSON being returned a 302 redirect was actually being returned. Which of course couldn't be parsed correctly

So try changing your code to:

```
var PictureUrl = "1713516952246958/picture?redirect=false";
var PictureResult = FB.Get(PictureUrl);
```

And you should be sweet!

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I created a request with the WebClient like this:

```
        WebClient p = new WebClient();
        p.QueryString.Add("access_token", accessToken);

        string responseData = p.DownloadString("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/me/picture");
```

and the reponse came back with an awkward data string that had several \0001 and the word "Photoshop 3.0" in it.

It appears the C# FaceBook SDK doesn't know how to process the response to the API route. The response appears to be binary data in some format from Photoshop.
Whenever I try the request and inspect it with postman or the browser it just shows the image as the request body, it doesn't show any sort of base64 encoding like I would have expected.
[Here is a small screen shot of the weird data.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMjhH.png)

It's probably an unimplemented feature that needs to be done in the SDK.